# Bootstrap row exceeds container-fluid's max-height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have following problem that I do not get fixed with the bootstrap grid system. The bootstrap Version is v4.5.2

I am setting a max-height(50vh) on a container-fluid which works fine. I then add a row to the container with 2 columns, but my images do not seem to resize properly, since the row simply exceeds the max-height of its parent container and adjusts to the image height.

Below you see the dev-tool images. I tried to use the "img-fluid" class, but it has no effect on my images whatsoever.

[This is the parent container-fluid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngz8K.png)

[This is the child-row that exceeds the container's max-height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iELb.png)

Where am I going wrong? This is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid view ">
    <div class="row h-100 d-flex align-items-center no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-6 pl-5">
            <h1>Just a simple Heading that should align in the middle</h1>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center img-fluid flex-nowrap overflow-hidden heroImages">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/600">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/600">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,header{
  height: 100%!important;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  color:black;
}

.view {
  max-height: 300px;
 /* max-height: 50vh; */
}

body {
  height: 100% !important;
  padding-top: 55px !important;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.84) !important;
}
```

Comment: Replace the dynamic code so that we can get the exact same output as in the image.

Comment: @m4n0 did so now. Used the same height to reproduce the issue. The original image height is 600px. I want the image to shrink to the max-height of 50vh that I set on the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the code above

```
.heroImages{
   height: 300px;
   display:flex;
  }
.heroImages img{
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  }
```

Parent div needs to have defined height and images inside that div needs to be displayed as block .